# Error Configuring Tomcat 7.0 with eclipse javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to configure server
While Configuring the Server Tomcat 7 in Eclipse It get hang and Shows error i am getting the following Error Please Resolve and Help An error has occurred. See error log for more details.

```
        !SESSION 2013-08-07 11:31:09.565 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2013-08-07 11:31:23.243
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.xml.XMLUtil.getDocumentBuilder(XMLUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.xml.Factory.loadDocument(Factory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat70Configuration.load(Tomcat70Configuration.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat70Configuration.importFromPath(Tomcat70Configuration.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServer.importRuntimeConfiguration(TomcatServer.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerWorkingCopy.importRuntimeConfiguration(ServerWorkingCopy.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerType.createServer(ServerType.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.ServerCreationCache.createServer(ServerCreationCache.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite.loadServerImpl(NewManualServerComposite.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite.handleTypeSelection(NewManualServerComposite.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite$1.serverTypeSelected(NewManualServerComposite.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.viewers.ServerTypeComposite$2.selectionChanged(ServerTypeComposite.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1725)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.viewers.ServerTypeComposite$3$1.run(ServerTypeComposite.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.actions.LaunchWizardAction.run(LaunchWizardAction.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: Please change your JDK version from 1.7.0_25 into 1.7.0_55 this version caused a lot a problems to me with appengine...

Comment: Thanks Ardi 
This is not an issue. I have changed my JDK version still this issue is exist

Comment: Finally the issue has resolved. it is because of JDK we need to setup JDK properly first then set the class path and configure Apache with eclipse